# Upload pics to a server using c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to upload a photo to one of our server in C++, the following is an excerpt of my testing code

```
//in main
ifstream fin("cloud.jpg");
ofstream fout("cloudcpy.jpg");

string data;
while ( fin )
    fin >> data;
fout << data;
fin.close();
fout.close();

return 0;
```

But the output file is not a copy, much more smaller than the original one. Anything wrong in my code?

Comment: `while (fin >> data)` would be better anyway (much nicer in general so that you only *use* good data), but why not just use a function that actually copies a file?

Comment: How much *smaller*? What is the original size?

Comment: @Jeffrey 10kB VS 1kB(76 bytes actually)

Comment: Oh, and the files are closed when the streams go out of scope. I don't particularly like putting things in that get done for me.

Comment: @chris There should be one, `read_file()` but seems some libs are missing I can't use it. And you are right! I've maked it work.

Comment: @zoujyjs, There is Boost Filesystem, which will be standard soon. There are also OS-specific options. I also found this gem in another SO answer: `fout << fin.rdbuf();`, which I can't believe I didn't think of.

Comment: Zeros will crop your string output.

Comment: @sje397 see my comments for the answer of jgmao

Comment: You also should open fin with the ios::binary flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not use string as the data type. Since JPEG file is not a textfile. Please try to use primitive type such as unsigned char or unsigned int to do it.

Comment: yeah, I just find out that the output file can't open by my gallery app.

Answer (score 1):

You need use 3rd party library. Please try [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)