# What is the difference between FileSink, StringSink, Filesource, StringSource Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, file-io, binaryfiles, crypto++

I am reading in an image, encrypting it, then decrypting it. The goal is to be looping this eventually and recording the time it takes for the process to complete. Currently what I have it reads the file in, then it encrypts it, encrypts it, the creates another file based on the recovered data. I don't need to make another file with the decrypted picture. Previously I had been using `StringSource` and `StringSink`, but that only worked for text files. I received some help at [How to read an image to a string for encrypting Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354548/how-to-read-an-image-to-a-string-for-encrypting-crypto/23355279#23355279) from and started using `FileSink` and `FileSource`.

What exactly is the difference between `FileSink`, `StringSink`, `FileSource` and `StringSource` ?

Also, in following example, why does cipher need to be set to something? Previously when I was just using `StringSource`, my string cipher was not initialized, but now that I am using `FileSource`, it needs to be initialized for it to work.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng_blowfish;

    SecByteBlock key_blowfish(Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    prng_blowfish.GenerateBlock(key_blowfish, key_blowfish.size());

    byte iv_blowfish[Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE];
    prng_blowfish.GenerateBlock(iv_blowfish, sizeof(iv_blowfish));

    string ifilename = "sample_files/1MB.jpg";
    string cipher = "1MB.enc";
    string rfilename = "r1MB.jpg";

    try
    {
        EAX<Blowfish>::Encryption e_blowfish;
        e_blowfish.SetKeyWithIV(key_blowfish, key_blowfish.size(), iv_blowfish, sizeof(iv_blowfish));

        std::ifstream ifile(ifilename.c_str(), ios::binary);
        std::ifstream::pos_type size = ifile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end).tellg();
        ifile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

        FileSource fs1(ifilename.c_str(), true, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(e_blowfish, new FileSink(cipher.c_str())));

        EAX<Blowfish>::Decryption d_blowfish;
        d_blowfish.SetKeyWithIV(key_blowfish, key_blowfish.size(), iv_blowfish, sizeof(iv_blowfish));

        FileSource fs2(cipher.c_str(), true, new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(d_blowfish, new FileSink(rfilename.c_str()), AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION));
    }
    catch (const Exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jww I got your code to read in the file! I have some questions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the difference between FileSink, StringSink, FileSourcem StringSource.

Sources, Filters and Sinks are part of the Pipeline design in Crypto++. Data flows from a source, is transformed by filters, and then ends at a sink.

All sources are interchangeable. All filters are interchangeable. And all sinks are interchangeable. For example, to switch between a `StringSink` and `FileSink`, you need to supply a filename with a `FileSink`. Otherwise, they operate the same. As another example, you can switch between a `HexEncoder` and `Base64Encoder` with no changes. As a final example, a `SocketSource` or `SocketSink` are going to need an IP address and port. What may (or may not) need to be changed depends on the object.

There are a number of sources. From [Source Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_source.html):

- `FileSource`
- `StringSource`
- `RandomNumberSource`
- `WindowPipeSource`
- `SocketSource`

There are a number of filters. You are using two of them - `AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter` and `AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter`. From [Filter Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_filter.html) and [FilterWithBufferedInput Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_filter_with_buffered_input.html):

- `HexEncoder`
- `HexEncoder`
- `Base32Encoder`
- `Base32Decoder`
- `Base64Encoder`
- `Base64Encoder`
- `DefaultEncryptor`
- `DefaultEncryptorWithMAC`
- `DefaultDecryptor`
- `DefaultDecryptorWithMAC`
- ...
- `StreamTransformationFilter`
- `AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter`
- `AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter`

There are a number of sinks. From [Sink Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_sink.html):

- `ArraySink`
- `BitBucket`
- `RandomNumberSink`
- `StringSink`
- `FileSink`
- `SocketSink`
- ...

There are some advanced topics, but I don't think they matter at the moment. For example, the role of `BufferedTransformation` and what it means if `Attachable` returns `true`. The answer is both Filters and Sinks are `BufferedTransformation`'s, and `Attachable = true` means its a Filter (otherwise its a Sink).

---

> ... in following example, why does cipher need to be set to something...

A `StringSource` and `StringSink` needs nothing because its just an array of byes in memory. A `FileSource` and `FileSink` needs a filename, and you are using `cipher` for the filename. You *have* to supply a filename because the objects a file/stream related. If you were using a `SocketSource` or `SocketSink`, then you would need to supply an IP address and port (more correctly, a `socket_t`).

Here are the `FileSource` constructors from [FileSource Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html). You are using the third constructor in your code.

```
FileSource (BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL)
FileSource (std::istream &in, bool pumpAll, BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL)
FileSource (const char *filename, bool pumpAll, BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL, bool binary=true)
```

Here are the `FileSink` constructors from [FileSink Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_sink.html). You are using the second constructor in your code.

```
FileSink (std::ostream &out)
FileSink (const char *filename, bool binary=true)
```